# Cross compling Gstreamer for ARM

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

Hi i was trying to compile Gstreamer for ARM platform. I am facing some issues as followed 
i have set INSTALL_PATH
installed glib at INSTALL_PATH

```
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ --host=arm-linux LDFLAGS=-L$INSTALL_PATH/lib CFLAGS=-I$INSTALL_PATH/include --build=i686-linux

in configuration process  
checking for GLIB... configure: 
configure: error: This package requires GLib >= 2.32.0 to compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing development libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```